# Python Tkinter piggyback to system bindings

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-menu

I am using TKinter Menu widet, and I want to bind additional keyboard key to system event binded to other keys already. What I mean is when the code snippet bellow is executed a simple menu is shown. When I press the 'Key-F10' the "File" label is highlighted and when I press any of the "Up" or "Down" arrow the menu gets exapnded (posted). This is at least the behaviour on Windows 8 OS.

I want to be able to expand the menu with the "Space" key once its highlighted with the '`<Key-F10>`', using the functional callback that for the "Up" "Down" keys - sort of piggyback the "Space" to the same binding. However I am not able to find how to do it. My code is shown bellow.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename


def popup(event):
   filemenu.post(filemenu.winfo_rootx(), filemenu.winfo_rooty())


root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit")

root.bind('<Button-3>', popup)
mainloop()
```

What I was able to find on my own for the print `root.bind_all('<Key-F10>')` is **: tk::WinMenuKey %W %N** which leads me to [here](https://github.com/mollstam/UnrealPy/blob/master/UnrealPyEmbed/Development/Python/2015.08.07-Python2710-x64-Source-vs2015/Python27/Source/tk-8.5.2.0/win/tkWinMenu.c) where the following is defined:

```
 *--------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * TkWinMenuKeyObjCmd --
 *
 *  This function is invoked when keys related to pulling down menus is
 *  pressed. The corresponding Windows events are generated and passed to
 *  DefWindowProc if appropriate. This cmd is registered as tk::WinMenuKey
 *  in the interp.
 *
 * Results:
 *  Always returns TCL_OK.
 *
 * Side effects:
 *  The menu system may take over and process user events for menu input.
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now how I can do for example `root.bind('<Key-Up>', tk::WinMenuKey)` to bind the Up key to the same event for pulling the menu. From what I have seen these events do not go through the `Tkinter.Menu.post/tk_popup` methods.

As an alternative i tried to  Tkinter.Menu.post in my registered callback for Muse button 3 with `filemenu.winfo_rootx()`, `filemenu.winfo_rooty()` as x, y coordinates however the menu is always expanded at the upper left part of the screen as shown in the screenshot. The behaviour is the same when I use `filemenu.winfo_x()`, `filemenu.winfo_y()`.

[image: Tkinter file menu poped at top left corner]

Comment: `root.bind('<Key-Up>', tk::WinMenuKey)` if root window always on **TOP**. Need listen whole system keyboard (with additional sub-process). You want global access but work on local side !

Comment: This just raises SyntaxError and there is no tk module for import.in order to listed for this event.